Proof of Theorem 7.11 in Professor Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds
This is a different question about the same topic as in
Proof of the Riemann curvature endomorphism as parallel transport around an infinitesimal loop(Thm 7.11 of Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds). I can follow the proof in the
book well enough
except for one thing. I cannot seem to prove that the resulting vector field $Z$
along $\Gamma$ is smooth. The errata tells us that "The resulting vector field
along $\Gamma$ is smooth by another application of Theorem A.42 as in the proof
of Lemma 7.8 ...". [Theorem A.42 is the Fundamental Theorem on Flows: Theorem 9.12
of Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.]
In the errata for Lemma 7.8, we were lucky enough to have Professor Lee tell us the form of the vector fields to use with Theorem A.42.
But I cannot seem to find vector fields to use with Theorem A.42 for the proof
of Theorem 7.11.
The two cases are different in the following way: in the proof
of Lemma 7.8, we construct curves whose derivatives are extremely simple,
basically a Kronecker delta function. But in Theorem 7.11, we are given the
curves (the main and transverse curves of $\Gamma\colon I\times I\to M$) and we
know nothing about their derivatives (other than they exist). Therefore, when
using the "parallelness" of certain vector fields along certain curves,
along with equation (4.15), the derivative
of the curve does not drop out for Theorem 7.11 as it does for Lemma 7.8,
and I don't see a way to include it in the
definition of the vector fields to be used with Theorem A.42.
In Tob Ernack's answer to the question linked above, he wrote
"... can be proven in the same way that Lee suggests proving that the vector field $Z$ obtained by parallel transporting $z$ along $t\mapsto\Gamma(0,t)$ and then along $s\mapsto\Gamma(s,t)$ is smooth. We just repeat the ideas again, essentially we have another system of ODEs whose initial conditions are based on the previous parallel transport, which is already known to be smooth." Unfortunately, I have
no clue as to which ODEs should be used and whether or not their properties are
covered in Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Appendix D and/or Introduction to
Riemannian Manifolds Theorem 4.31.
So, my question is:
$\bullet$ Can $Z$ be proven smooth using Theorem A.42 as suggested, and if so,
$\bullet$ what vector fields should be used, and if not
$\bullet$ how do you prove $Z$ is smooth?

EDIT: I just realized your question is asking about smoothness of the vector field $Z$ rather than for the parallel transport along the whole loop. For smoothness of $Z$ you just need the smoothness result for $F_2$ below, because $Z = F_2$.
Here are the notes I took when working out the details of this proof. It was a while ago so I'll have to refresh my memory to discuss if there are issues.
For simplicity of notation, let $S = \partial_s \Gamma$ and $T = \partial_t \Gamma$.
Define a function $F: I \times I \to T_pM$ by
$F(s, t) = P_{s,0}^{0,0} \circ P_{s,t}^{s,0} \circ P_{0,t}^{s,t} \circ P_{0,0}^{0,t}(z)$ in terms of the parallel transport operators defined in the statement of Theorem 7.11.
I will show that $F$ is smooth in a neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$.
Let $(U, (x^i))$ be a smooth chart for $M$ centered at $p$ for which we
also have a smooth local trivialization $(x^i, v^i)$ for $TM$ around $(p, 0)$.
Then let $\varepsilon > 0$ be small enough that $Γ(s, t) \subseteq U$ for all $|s|, |t| < \varepsilon$.
Let $C_\varepsilon = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ be the square neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$.
First define a function $F_1: I \to TM$ by $F_1(t) = P_{0,0}^{0,t}(z)$.
This function is smooth because of Theorem 4.32.
Next define $F_2: I \times I \to TM$ by $F_2(s, t) = P_{0, t}^{s,t}(F_1(t))$.
For a fixed $t$, we can define $F_{2,t}: I \to TM$ by $F_{2,t}(s) = F_2(s, t)$.
For $(s, t)$ in $C_ε$, we can work in coordinates, and the components
of $F_{2,t}$ must be solutions to the following system of ODEs:
$$\dot{F}_{2,t}^k(s) = -F_{2,t}^j(s) S^i(s, t) \Gamma_{ij}^k(\Gamma(s, t))$$
$$F_{2,t}^k(0) = F_1^k(t)$$
This system can be rewritten to remove explicit dependency on $s$
and $t$ except in the initial conditions, by adding unknowns $g(u)$ and $h(u)$ which will replace $s$ and $t$:
$$\dot{g}(u) = 1$$
$$\dot{h}(u) = 0$$
$$\dot{F}_{2,t}^k(u) = -F_{2,t}^j(u) S^i(g(u), h(u)) \Gamma_{ij}^k(\Gamma(g(u), h(u)))$$
$$g(0) = 0$$
$$h(0) = t$$
$$F_{2,t}^k(0) = F_1^k(t)$$
This in turn means that the solutions $(g(u), h(u), F_{2,t}(u))$ are
integral curves of the smooth vector field $W$ on $C_\varepsilon \times \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$W_{(s, t, v)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg\vert_{(s, t, v)} - v^j S^i(s, t) \Gamma_{ij}^k(\Gamma(s, t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial v^k}\bigg\vert_{(s, t, v)}$$
Let $\theta: \mathcal{D} \to C_\varepsilon \times \mathbb{R}^n$ be the flow of $W$ as given by Theorem A.42.
Then $(g(u), h(u), F_{2,t}(u)) = \theta(u, 0, t, F_1(t))$ for $(u, t) \in C_\varepsilon$.
Since $F_1$ and $\theta$ are smooth, this shows that $F_2$ is smooth on $C_\varepsilon$.
Next define $F_3: I \times I \to TM$ by $F_3(s, t) = P_{s,t}^{s,0} F_2(s, t)$.
This is the parallel transport of $F_2(s, t)$ along the curve $\tau \to \Gamma(s, \tau)$ from $\tau = t$ to $\tau = 0$. There is a subtlety here because we are moving "backward" in time along the curve, so the "initial" condition starts at $t$ instead of $0$, and we are interested in the "final" value at $0$.
For a fixed $s$, we can define $F_{3,s}: I \to TM$ by $F_{3,s}(\tau) = F_3(s, \tau)$.
For $(s, \tau) \in C_\varepsilon$, we can work in coordinates, and the
components of $F_{3,s}$ must be solutions to the following system of ODEs:
$$\dot{F}_{3,s}^k(\tau) = -F_{3,s}^j(\tau) T^i(s, \tau) \Gamma_{ij}^k(\Gamma(s, \tau))$$
$$F_{3,s}^k(t) = F_2^k(s, t)$$
This system can be rewritten to remove explicit dependency on $s$ and $\tau$
except in the initial conditions, by adding unknowns $g(u)$ and $h(u)$ replacing $s$ and $\tau$:
$$\dot{g}(u) = 0$$
$$\dot{h}(u) = 1$$
$$\dot{F}_{3,s}^k(u) = -F_{3,s}^j(u) T^i(g(u), h(u)) \Gamma_{ij}^k(\Gamma(g(u), h(u)))$$
$$g(t) = s$$
$$h(t) = t$$
$$F_{3,s}^k(t) = F_2^k(s, t)$$
This in turn means that the solutions $(g(u), h(u), F_{3,s}(u))$ are
integral curves of the smooth vector field $W$ on $C_\varepsilon \times \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$W_{(s, \tau, v)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\bigg\vert_{(s, \tau, v)} - v^j T^i(s, \tau) \Gamma_{ij}^k(\Gamma(s, \tau)) \frac{\partial}{\partial v^k}\bigg\vert_{(s, \tau, v)}$$
Let $\theta: \mathcal{D} \to C_\varepsilon \times \mathbb{R}^n$ be the flow of $W$ as given by Theorem A.42.
Then $(g(u), h(u), F_{3,s}(u)) = \theta(u - t, s, t, F_2(s, t))$ for $(s, t) \in C_\varepsilon$ and $u$ in $(t - \varepsilon, t + \varepsilon)$. Since $F_2$ and $\theta$ are smooth, this shows that
$F_3(s, t)$ is smooth on $C_\varepsilon$.
Finally, we have $F(s, t) = P_{s,0}^{0,0} F_3(s, t)$.
We can use the same argument as above to show that $F$ is smooth
for $s, t \in C_\varepsilon$.
We could probably also show that $F$ is smooth on $I \times I$ by partitioning $I \times I$ into small squares that each fit into a coordinate chart and use a gluing argument. But we don’t need this in the proof of the Theorem 7.11, we only
need to know that it is smooth in a neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$. So I haven't tried to show this rigorously.

When you rewrote the system for $\dot{F}{2,t}^k(s)$, you turned it into a system that is no longer covered by Theorem 4.31 since it is not linear any more. If you let $V^k=F{2,t}^k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$, $V^{n+1}=s$, and $V^{n+2}=t$, and ask what is $A^1_1(u)$ in Theorem 4.31 (4.20), you would say it has to be $-S^i(V^{n+1}(u),V^{n+2}(u))\Gamma_{i1}^1(\Gamma(V^{n+1}(u),V^{n+2}(u)))$. But $A(u)$ cannot have an explicit dependence on $V$.

@JeffRubin I am not using Theorem 4.31 on the reformulated system, I use the fundamental theorem of flows directly (Theorem A.42). I used Theorem 4.31 to argue smoothness of $F_{2,t}^k$ with respect to $s$ but that might be superfluous. The main point is that $(s(u), t(u), F_{2,t}(u))$ is an integral curve of the vector field $W$.

And then we use the flow of $W$ to express $(s(u), t(u), F_{2,t}(u))$ in a way that is manifestly smooth in $u$ and $t$ jointly: $(s(u), t(u), F_{2,t}(u)) = \theta(u, 0, t, F_1(t))$. Now $F_2(u, t) = F_{2,t}(u)$ is a component of the smooth function, so it has to be smooth by composition with a projection.

I do apologize for the abuse of notation using $t$ both as a variable and as a function symbol for $t(u)$.

Also my argument is going backwards to derive the required $W$. But really you should start from the definition of $W$ and its flow $\theta$, and then see that the components of the curves $\theta(u, 0, t, F_1(t))$ in $u$ satisfy the system of equations for $g, h, F_{2,t}$, and hence that $F_{2,t}$ satisfies the ODE for parallel transport (using $g(u) = u$ and $h(u) = t$ and evaluating at $u = s$).

Ah, that makes sense to me now. I will do a more thorough check later, but for now, I will accept your answer. Nicely done!

It all checks out!
